# Why is the [established user] privilege there

Tags: discussion

1st of all there is no problem with showing 1 rep users the vote count of a question or answer
2nd If someone wants to see the vote count it is possible by seeing the reputation change of the post's owner, It is difficult but you can even write some code to automate it

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/1007/293308